# My cart is not displaying

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, ccavenue, storefront

I have added one product through woo-commerce, But in front-end after clicking add to cart and then clicking on view cart it displays nothing but `Post Navigation` and a link to go back, How can I get this working.

I have installed ccavenue as my payment gateway, and using custom theme, and I followed all the procedure to get custom theme compatible with woo-commerce as provided in its documentation like duplicate `page.php` to `woocommerce.php` and adding hooks,

when I activates woocommerce storefront theme, Everything works perfect, But when I activates my custom theme, cart and checkout page doesnt display. only header, footer and "POST NAVIGATION" in body gets displayed.

following is checkout page screen when woocommerce storefront theme is active;

[image: checkout form on checkout page while woocommerce storefront theme is active]

following is checkout page screen when custom theme is active;

[image: Post Navigation is written instead of checkout form on checkout page while custom theme is active]

what I want is to display checkout page as in image1 of storefront theme in my custom theme and/or all functionality of storefront theme if possible.

Please get me out of this.

Comment: Have you added the `[woocommerce_cart]' shortcode to your cart page? A link to the site would also help.

Comment: Yes I have added, But the problem is its working on wooommerce theme, But not on my custom theme.

Comment: Then it can be any number of problems; start by [opening your wp-config.php file and turning on debugging.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Example_wp-config.php_for_Debugging) Then post any error messages that you see.

Comment: See I have edited the question.

Comment: OK, I can help, but the problem could be caused by a number of things, so let's work through them. Can you confirm: 1. There is definitely a `checkout` page. 2. This page has the `[woocommerce_checkout]` shortcode inserted into the content. 3. What page template are you using for the checkout page? Is it the default page template? If so, look for the `page.php` file and confirm if it contains `the_content()`.

Comment: Actually the custom theme was developed by a former employee by scratch.So it had limitations like no cart/checkout page so what I did is installed child theme generater plugin. And made child theme of "woocommerce storefront" theme as "sakar storefront child". So my child theme had 3 files in start, 1st theme image, 2nd functions.php and 3rd:style.css. now what I did is I copied all the files except these 3 from my custom sakar theme to newly created child theme, but it still creating problems, and my cart and checkout is not working  may be I created child theme in wrong way.

Comment: A couple of things:
1) The theme doesn't need to have a page template specifically for the checkout; you simply create a page called 'checkout' and add the shortcode, so you might not even need a child theme.
2) You need to [read up on how to create child themes](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/) as your approach seems wrong. Child themes override the parent on a file by file basis. If you're copying *everything* from the parent theme then all you're doing is duplicating it. 
You should still confirm the three points mentioned previously before proceeding.

Comment: Hi,
I followed all your comments, and created a child theme of storefront and copied my old theme's contents in it, So it worked perfect.

I requests you to write an answer below of all your above comments.

Comment: Answer added below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be caused by a number of issues, so you need to check/confirm/correct the following:

1. Is there definitely a `checkout` page?
2. Does the page have the `[woocommerce_checkout]` shortcode inserted into the content.
3. Confirm if the page template for your page is definitely outputting the content. If using the default page template look for the `page.php` file and confirm if it contains `the_content()`
4. The theme doesn't *need* to have a page template specifically for the checkout; you can simply create a page called 'checkout' and add the shortcode, so you might not even need a child theme.
5. You need to read up on [how to create child themes](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/) as your approach seems wrong. Child themes override the parent on a file by file basis. If you're copying everything from the parent theme then all you're doing is duplicating it.